# associating one class with another. master/slave classes

Tags: java

in my main program (given to me by teacher to test the program, i have to build classes that operate with his main program) i have code that looks like this

**Plug aPlug = aSwitch.wherePlug();**

Plug is another class

aSwitch is an object that was created earlier in the code (Switch aSwitch = newSwitch();)

whereplug() is a method in the *Switch* class that is "associated" with *Plug* class.

*public Plug wherePlug(){

}*

everytime i try coding and return a value, i always get the incompatible type error, cannot convert plug to boolean.

my question is how does association with classes work? with one class and another. in another words one class is dependent on the other.

the purpose of the program is when a switch is toggeled it changes the state the of the plug state.

i have added the code beneath, can any one tell me how to fix it.

public class StudentDriver{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Testing Switch Methods\n_________________________________");
    System.out.println("Making a new Switch with the no constructor having no parameters");
    Switch aSwitch= new Switch();
    System.out.println("After construction, Switch is on?: " + aSwitch.state());
    aSwitch.flip();
    System.out.println("After flipping, Switch is on?: " + aSwitch.state());
    System.out.println("Making a new Switch with constructor having its parameter set to true");
    aSwitch= new Switch(true);
    System.out.println("After construction, Switch is on?: " + aSwitch.state());
    aSwitch.flip();
    System.out.println("After flipping, Switch is on?: " + aSwitch.state());


    System.out.println("\nTesting Plug Methods\n_________________________________");
    ***Plug aPlug = aSwitch.wherePlug();***
    System.out.println("Switch is on? " + aSwitch.state() +
        " Plug is on? " + aPlug.state());
    aSwitch.flip();
    System.out.println("Switch is on? " + aSwitch.state() +
        " Plug is on? " + aPlug.state());
    }
}
```

public class Switch
{

```
boolean stateSw;     
public Switch()    {
   stateSw = false;}

public Switch(boolean initalState)    {
    stateSw = initalState;    }

public boolean state()    {
    return stateSw;    }

public void flip()    {
    if(stateSw == true)        {
        stateSw = false;}
    else if (stateSw == false)        {
        stateSw = true;}    }

***public Plug wherePlug()    {
return stateSw;  }***
```

}

public class Plug{

```
boolean statePlug = false;    

public Plug()    {
    statePlug = false;}

public boolean state()    {                
    return statePlug;}
```

}

Comment: Please post a small snippet of code that shows what's giving you trouble.

Comment: I'd need to see your code to be sure, but it sounds like you've written a method that has a signature of something like this: `public bool wherePlug()`, and you're trying to return a Plug when it expects a return type of boolean.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is this:

```
public Plug wherePlug() {
    return stateSw;  
}
```

You're declaring that `wherePlug()` must return a `Plug`, but instead you're returning a `boolean` (i.e. `stateSw`).

It's unclear what you're trying to do here, so I can't say exactly how to fix it. However, see if you can change you code around so that `wherePlug()` does NOT return a `Plug` (or maybe you can get rid of `wherePlug()` entirely). This would result in class `Switch` not having any dependencies on class `Plug`; eliminating dependencies is almost always a good idea.

Comment: I know the problem is there but i don't know how to fix it. I can't get rid of wherePlug() entirely because having that as a method is a part of the assignment. How do you make it so it does not return a Plug? What i am trying to do is alter the state of Plug and state of Switch at the same time.

Comment: Did your teacher give any more details at all about the `wherePlug()` method? Altering the state of a `Plug` within a different class (i.e. `Switch`) doesn't strike me as a good design. Instead, alter the states in a static function outside of `Plug` or `Switch`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Plug object inside your Switch class, call it idontcare

```
public Plug wherePlug()
    {
        return idontcare;
    }
```

Also, you need to make statePlug inside the Plug idontcare to be true when you return the plug idontcare. How? well, that is your homework. =)